# Configuring Packer with Neovim

Tags: lua, neovim, packer

I'm trying to switch over my current setup for Neovim (using Vim Plug) to Packer and I'm having trouble.

My Neovim is loaded from `~/.config/nvim/init.lua` which sources all of my plugin and other settings. They live mostly inside of a `~/lua` folder (the "main Imports") section of my configuration, including my actual `plug-plugins.lua` file that references all of my plugins.

```
-- Main Imports
require("settings")
require("colors")
require("mappings")
require("functions")
require("autocommands")
require("plug-plugins")
...
```

Later in the same `init.lua` file, I'm sourcing plugin specific settings for all of these plugins. In order to get my directory working currently, I'm installing everything with `:PlugInstall` and it works fine.

```
...

-- Plugin-specific settings
require("plugin-settings/fzf")
require("plugin-settings/fugitive")
require("plugin-settings/ultisnips")
require("plugin-settings/coc")
require("plugin-settings/treesitter")
require("plugin-settings/miscellaneous")
require("plugin-settings/toggle-terminal")
```

### Installing Packer

The [installation](https://github.com/wbthomason/packer.nvim) steps for Packer are pretty sparse, and merely state that you should clone the repository to somewhere in your "packpath" but I'm not really clear what that means. When I'm inside Neovim, and I press `:set packpath?` I get the following paths:

```
packpath=~/.config/nvim,/etc/xdg/nvim,~/.local/share/nvim/site,/usr/local/share/nvim/site,/usr/share/nvim/site,/usr/local/Cellar/neovim/HEAD-b74916c_1/share/nvim/runtime,/usr/local/Cel
lar/neovim/HEAD-b74916c_1/lib/nvim,/usr/share/nvim/site/after,/usr/local/share/nvim/site/after,~/.local/share/nvim/site/after,/etc/xdg/nvim/after,~/.config/nvim/after
```

This makes me think that I'm able to just clone the respository to `~/.config/nvim` which is the first path listed. I'm not really sure what to do next though, or if this is even right.

Can anyone help? What are the basic steps to getting Packer installed (I'm on MacOS 11.6).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

i did recently moved from vim-plug to packer, as per docs when you do git clone of the repo the path provided in readme for installation is `~/.local/share/nvim/site/pack/packer`.After successful clone you can start using packer in your plugins.lua as below.

```
return require('packer').startup(function()
    use 'wbthomason/packer.nvim'
end)
```

you can check the installation by running `:PackerSync` this will fetch (git clone) the plugin in to the packerpath which is `~/.local/share/nvim/site/pack/packer`
Hope this is what you looking for?

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same situation and it turned out to just be a naming conflict. I had named my local nvim config file `lua/packer.lua` and changing that fixed the issue.